# kubernetes system pods are deploying on worker instead of master node

Tags: kubernetes

i have created a K8S cluster and installed a metrics server on it for monitor the resources usage, but notices that the pods which helps to run k8s system along with metrics server are deploying on worker nodes , after the worker nodes down k8s wont working.

i have done some R&D for this and got a solution called taint and toleration ,is it suitable for current scenario?

I am expecting all the system pods to be on master nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Kubernetes system Pods are meant to be deployed on every node, like the Container Network Interface Plugin (Calico, Flannel ...)  or the kube-proxy. What kind of system pods are we talking about ?

If your cluster fails after one of your worker nodes fail, the same incident would happen if your master node failed, so the problem might be somewhere else.

But yes, taints and tolerations would allow specific Pods to be scheduled on specific nodes.

Comment: yes, i meant the same system pods like Network Interface Plugin (Calico, Flannel ...) or the kube-proxy etc.

so , cant we move it to only master node ? so that we can deploy other application's pods on worker nodes only.

Comment: No you cannot move them to the master node only as they're meant to be deployed on every node. 

I don't know what provider/tool you're using to deploy your cluster, but if you go in the kube-system namespace you should see that these system Pods (like calico or kube-proxy) are deployed using a DaemonSet, which is a ressource that allows to deploy a Pod on every Node.

Some providers allow to define the Master Nodes as Masters only so no workload will be deployed on them. Other providers don't even allow you to see Master nodes (like GKE), so no workload will be deployed on them.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use nodeSelector. It's like assign a label to master node and then use "nodeSelector" in your pod's yaml/menifest file. Pod will be deployed on node which have the label assigned. more info @ https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes/

Comment: but how we can configure it while initiating the cluster for deploying the system pods, here i am talking about the system pods like Network Interface Plugin (Calico, Flannel ...) or the kube-proxy.